# Can't update parent window unless child is in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following code works fine...

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Home Page
        <br>Name:<br><input type="text" id="name">
        <br><a href="#" id="loginlink" onclick="window.open('login.html','_blank');">LOG IN</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log In</title>
        <script>
            function updateHomePage() {
                opener.document.getElementById("loginlink").text = "LOG OUT";
                opener.document.getElementById("name").value = "Joe Blow";
                self.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="javascript:updateHomePage();">
            <div>
                Login Window
                <br>Email: <input type="email" id="email">
                <br>Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <br><input type="submit" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I want login.html to open in the same tab, not in a new tab. If I use '_self' instead of '_blank', I can no longer update index.html. The opener statements throw the following error..."Cannot set property 'text' of null". Is there a way to open login.html in the same tab and still be able to update the parent page?

Comment: If you open login.html in the same tab, how can you update the parent page when it's no longer there?

Comment: You could use a modal instead of opening a completely separate window.